# React Navigation - Stack.Navigator screenProps not working

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-props, react-navigation-stack

I have the following code which creates a simple stack navigator for 2 components `Login` and `List`. I have a `useState` hook in the file with the navigator (`App.js`) and I want to pass down the setter and getter to each of the screens. I have tried using `screenProps` on the stack navigator but after logging the props passed to each of the components, the variables do not appear.

**TL;DR** I need to pass props from the `Stack.Navigator` down to each screen

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenProps={{setVariable, variable}}>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Login"
      component={Login}
      options={navOptions}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="List"
      component={List}
      options={navOptions}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use React's context API

```
// MyContext.js
export const MyContext = React.createContext();
```

```js
// App.js
const context = React.useMemo(() => ({
  setVariable,
  variable
}), [variable]);

return (
  <MyContext.Provider value={context}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={navOptions}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="List"
          component={List}
          options={navOptions}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </MyContext.Provider>
);
```

```js
// Home.js
const variable = React.useContext(MyContext);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html#global-props-with-screenprops